# *resumable * html5 drag-drop file uploads

Tags: html

I'd like to know if it's possible/advisable to build the following JPG uploader:
- use html5 drag-drop to select files for upload
- filter drop list to upload JPG files only
- use html5 to save upload list in local storage
- initiate html5 file uploads

And in case the uploads did not successfully complete, on reload of page:
- check local storage for list of uploaded files
- resume upload from last successful file.

Is it possible/What kind of user interaction is necessary to allow HTML5 to get a list of OS filepaths and initiate file uploads?

The idea is to make easy/reliable to upload say 500 JPGs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe these can help: https://github.com/valums/file-uploader and https://github.com/newbamboo/rack-raw-upload

[EDIT]

Now I use [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) on all my projects

Comment: Not really resumable, but I used the valums file uploader as a stop-gap.